# Why is java telling me the string are not matching?

Tags: java

I'm reading in from a text file.
every time the frame number changes I need to check if the ipv6 address is changed.
every time I compare the strings it tells me they don't match even after setting the value to the source address.

Comment: can you post your codes please.

Comment: How are you comparing? Share the code, inputs and error.

Comment: Most likely you are using `==` instead of `.equals`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post code related to your problem. Without it we can't give you proper answer, but only guesses.

Comment: Let us know if you get it working!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're using == instead of .equals()?

e.g.

```
ipv6_src_hold.trim() != ipv6_src_host.trim() && ipv6_dst_hold.trim() !=ipv6_src_host.trim()){
```

->

```
(! ipv6_src_hold.trim().equals(ipv6_src_host.trim() &&!ipv6_dst_hold.trim().equals(ipv6_src_host.trim())){
```

Comment: Maybe this is a comment ;)

Comment: here is my code that is doing the matching   sorry having a tuff time with this editor/ webpage  if( ipv6_src_hold.trim() != ipv6_src_host.trim() && ipv6_dst_hold.trim() != ipv6_src_host.trim()){
 System.out.println("src " + frame_Num + "\n" + ipv6_src_hold + "\n" + ipv6_src_host ); 
 ipv6_src_hold = ipv6_src_host.trim();
 System.out.println("dst " + frame_Num + "\n" + ipv6_dst_hold + "\n" + ipv6_dst_host); 
 ipv6_dst_hold = ipv6_dst_host.trim();
 frame_Num = Integer.parseInt(frame_number); 
}

Comment: Maybe change the blabla != to ! blabla.equals(bla) 
e.g. .._dst_hold.trim() != ipv6_... to (! ..dst_hold.trim().equals(ipv6...)

Comment: And Peter firstly thanks for the input, second I wasn't able to use comments til it got upvoted . Third I might've hit the issue :) but i did write these more comment-like then answer-like, will try to improve

Comment: @fredg. Please do not post code as a comment, it's totally unreadable. Edit your original post and format it.

Comment: Edited my answer instead of adding the specific example as another comment